Automatic Horizontal Scroll Working But Manual Scroll Doesn't
I want a scroll bar that is able to automatically scroll as well as having two buttons that be manually clicked to scroll right/left.
Problem:

Manual scroll Buttons are not working but the automatic scroll is, They are using the exact same code to scroll: adverts.scrollBy({ left: 20, behavior: 'smooth' });

Even after I remove the automatic scroll code the manual scroll buttons do not work.


What I need help with:
Having Manual scroll buttons and Automatic scroll working at the same time.


.scrollbar {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.scroll {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.adverts {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: grey;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.advert {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    
}

.advert .img {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
    height: 60%;
    outline: black 3px solid;
}
<div class="scrollbar">
    <div class="adverts">
        <a href="" class="advert w">
            <div class="img"></div>

        </a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert w"></a>
        <a href="" class="advert b"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll right" onclick="scrollLeft">right</div>
<div class="scroll left" onclick="scrollRight">left</div>

<script>
    const adverts = document.querySelector('.adverts');

    //Manual Scroll
    function scrollRight() {
        adverts.scrollLeft -= 100;
    }
    function scrollLeft() {
        adverts.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }

    // Automatic Scroll (Wait 3 seconds before start)
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
        adverts.scrollBy({ left: 20, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }, 10);

    }, 3000);
    var text = 0;
</script>




I don't understand the onclick="scrollLeft" - why isn't it calling a function? And please show the relevant Javascript.

I have found the problem it is with "onclick", for some reason it wont call the function so i added an addEventListener in the script and got rid of the onclick and it is working now (the java script is in the 2nd block of code below the html)

Your function call in the onclick should have had () that was why it wasn’t called.

There was a problem with the "onclick" as it was not calling the function so i changed it to a "addEventListener" and it is working now
<div id="clicker" >right</div>

<script>
    const adverts = document.querySelector('.adverts');
    const button = document.getElementById('clicker');
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        scrollRight();
    });
    

    function scrollRight() {
        adverts.scrollLeft += 100;
    }

